# Serialization of Custom object from an ArrayList to a txt file

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization

I have a base abstract class Contact and two sub classes Person and Organization.
I'm doing an exercise where i have to serialize the objects that i'm storing inside
ArrayList contactsArray = new ArrayList<>();
as long i add Person object and Organization object to it i have no problem, cause, correct me if i'm wrong even if i declared the ArrayList it can store subclasses type objects. So till then it worked, but if i try now
to serialize it i get the error. I read that all sub classes of a super class that implement the serialize interface don't need to implement it themself because they are already inheriting it.
Once i initialize the object i choose between Person or Organization i store it in the
ArrayList contactsArray = new ArrayList<>();
after that i get the error exactly when it tries to execute this line.

```
    oos.writeObject(obj);
```

my question is:
in my situation, with a direct inheritance, am i doing wrong implementing the Serialization interface only in the Superclass Contact? Is the error coming from my bad implementation of it? Or it's just because i'm doing something wrong with the classes types and the ArrayList i use? To be more precise when i pass it as parameter to the method:

```
    serializeContact(ArrayList<Contact> obj)
```

Could it be because i didn't define well the file path? The txt file is in the same folder of the class java files, maybe it can't be written and it needs some kind of writing permission?

This is the error i get:

```
    java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.Scanner
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:897)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1145)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
        at contacts.App.serializeContact(App.java:76)
        at contacts.App.addRecord(App.java:61)
        at contacts.App.menu(App.java:167)
        at contacts.Main.main(Main.java:5)
    Something went wrong
    [menu] Enter action (add, list, search, count, exit):
```

Below my full code:
contacts/Main.java

```
    package contacts;
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            App application = new App();
            application.menu();
        }
    }
```

contacts/App.java

```
    package contacts;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    class App {
        ArrayList<Contact> contactsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        public void countRecords() {
            System.out.println("The Phone Book has " + this.contactsArray.size() + " 
            records.\n");
        }
    
        public void listRecords() {
            if(this.contactsArray.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("No records to list!\n");
                menu();
            } else {
                showRecordFields();
            }
            System.out.println("Enter index to show info: ");
            int choiceRecord = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine()) - 1;
            if(this.contactsArray.get(choiceRecord).isPerson()) {
                Person selection = (Person) this.contactsArray.get(choiceRecord);
                selection.showInfo();
            } else {
                Organization selection = (Organization) this.contactsArray.get(choiceRecord);
                selection.showInfo();
            }
        }
    
        public void showRecordFields() {
            if(this.contactsArray.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("No records to list!\n");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.contactsArray.size(); i++) {
                    if(this.contactsArray.get(i).isPerson()) {
                        Person selection = (Person) this.contactsArray.get(i);
                        System.out.println((i + 1) + "." + " " + selection.getName() + " " + 
      selection.getSurname());
                    } else {
                        Organization selection = (Organization) this.contactsArray.get(i);
                        System.out.println((i + 1) + "." + " " + selection.nameOganization);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        public void addRecord() {
            System.out.println("Enter the type (person, organization): ");
            String typeofcontact = sc.nextLine();
            switch (typeofcontact) {
                case "person":
                    Person person = new Person();
                    this.contactsArray.add(person);
                    serializeContact(contactsArray);
                    break;
                case "organization":
                    Organization organization = new Organization();
                    this.contactsArray.add(organization);
                    serializeContact(contactsArray);
                    break;
            }
        }
    
        public void serializeContact(ArrayList<Contact> obj) {
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("./contacts/contactsdata.txt");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(obj);
                oos.close();
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    
        public void removeRecord() {
            if(this.contactsArray.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("No records to remove!\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Select a record: ");
                this.showRecordFields();
                int choiceRecord = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine()) - 1;
                this.contactsArray.remove(choiceRecord);
                System.out.println("The record removed!\n");
            }
        }
    
        public void editRecord() {
            if(this.contactsArray.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("No records to edit!\n");
            } else {
                this.showRecordFields();
                System.out.println("Select a record: ");
                int choiceRecord = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine()) - 1;
                if(this.contactsArray.get(choiceRecord).isPerson()) {
                    Person selection = (Person) this.contactsArray.get(choiceRecord);
                    selection.editContact();
                    selection.setDateLastEdit();
                } else {
                    Organization selection = (Organization) this.contactsArray.get(choiceRecord);
                    selection.editContact();
                    selection.setDateLastEdit();
                }
                System.out.println("The record updated!\n");
            }
        }
    
        public String menuOptionsSearch(Scanner sc) {
            System.out.println("[search] Enter action ([number], back, again): ");
            return sc.nextLine();
        }
    
        public void menuSearch() {
            switch (this.menuOptionsSearch(sc)) {
                case "back":
                    this.countRecords();
                    menu();
                case "again":
                    this.editRecord();
                    menu();
                case "":
                    this.removeRecord();
                    menu();
            }
        }
    
        public String menuOptions(Scanner sc)  {
            System.out.println("[menu] Enter action (add, list, search, count, exit): ");
            return sc.nextLine();
        }
    
        public void search() {
            if(this.contactsArray.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("No records to search!\n");
                menu();
            }
            String choiceSearch = sc.nextLine();
    
        }
    
        public void menu() {
            switch (this.menuOptions(sc)) {
                case "count":
                    this.countRecords();
                    menu();
                case "edit":
                    this.editRecord();
                    menu();
    //            case "remove":
    //                this.removeRecord();
    //                menu();
    //            case "search":
    //                this.search();
    //                menu();
                case "add":
                    this.addRecord();
                    menu();
                case "list":
                    this.listRecords();
                    menu();
                case "exit":
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong field name");
                    menu();
            }
        }
    }
```

contacts/Contact.java

```
    package contacts;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    
    abstract class Contact implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7L;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String number;
        LocalDateTime dateCreation;
        LocalDateTime dateLastEdit;
    
        abstract void showInfo();
        abstract void editContact();
    
        public String getNumber() {
            return this.number;
        }
    
        public void setNumber() {
            System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
            checkNumber(sc.nextLine());
        }
    
        public void checkNumber(String number) {
            String regex = "^\\+?(\\(\\w+\\)|\\w+[ -]\\(\\w{2,}\\)|\\w+)([ -]\\w{2,})*";
            if(number.matches(regex)) {
                this.number = number;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong number format!");
                this.number = "[no number]";
            }
        }
    
        public boolean isPerson() {
            return this.getClass() == Person.class;
        }
    
        public void setDateCreation() {
            this.dateCreation = LocalDateTime.now().withSecond(0).withNano(0);
        }
    
        public void setDateLastEdit() {
            this.dateLastEdit = LocalDateTime.now().withSecond(0).withNano(0);
        }
    }
```

contacts/Person.java

```
    package contacts;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.time.DateTimeException;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    
    public class Person extends Contact {
        String name;
        String surname;
        String birthdate;
        String gender;
        public Person() {
            setName();
            setSurname();
            setBirthdate();
            setGender();
            setNumber();
            setDateCreation();
            setDateLastEdit();
            System.out.println("The record added.\n");
        }
    
        public void showInfo() {
            System.out.println("Name: " + this.name +
                    "\nSurname: " + this.surname +
                    "\nBirth date: " + this.birthdate +
                    "\nGender: " + this.gender +
                    "\nNumber: " + this.number +
                    "\nTime created: " + this.dateCreation +
                    "\nTime last edit: " + this.dateLastEdit + "\n");
        }
    
        public void setName() {
            System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
            this.name = sc.nextLine();
        }
    
        public void setSurname() {
            System.out.println("Enter the surname: ");
            this.surname = sc.nextLine();
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    
        public String getSurname() {
            return this.surname;
        }
    
        public void setGender() {
            System.out.println("Enter the gender (M, F): ");
            String choice = sc.nextLine();
            if(choice.equals("M")){
                this.gender = choice;
            } else if (choice.equals("F")) {
                this.gender = choice;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Bad gender!");
                this.gender = "[no data]";
            }
        }
    
        public String getGender() {
            return this.gender;
        }
    
        public void setBirthdate() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter the birth date: ");
                String choice;
                choice = sc.nextLine();
                this.birthdate = LocalDate.parse(choice).toString();
            } catch (DateTimeException dateTimeException) {
                System.out.println("Bad birth date!");
                this.birthdate = "[no data]";
            }
        }
    
        public String getBirthdate() {
            return this.birthdate;
        }
    
    
        public void editContact() {
            String choiceField;
            System.out.println("Select a field (name, surname, birth, gender, number): ");
            choiceField = sc.nextLine();
            switch (choiceField) {
                case "name":
                    this.setName();
                    break;
                case "surname":
                    this.setSurname();
                    break;
                case "birth":
                    this.setBirthdate();
                    break;
                case "gender":
                    this.setGender();
                    break;
                case "number":
                    this.setNumber();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong field name");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
contacts/Organization.java
package contacts;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Organization extends Contact {

    String nameOganization;
    String address;


    public Organization() {
        setOraganizationName();
        setOrganizationAdress();
        setNumber();
        setDateCreation();
        setDateLastEdit();
        System.out.println("The record added.\n");
    }

    public void showInfo() {
        System.out.println("Organization name: " + this.nameOganization +
                "\nAddress: " + this.address +
                "\nNumber: " + this.number +
                "\nTime created: " + this.dateCreation +
                "\nTime last edit: " + this.dateLastEdit + "\n");
    }

    public void setOraganizationName() {
        System.out.println("Enter the organization name: ");
        this.nameOganization = sc.nextLine();
    }

    public void setOrganizationAdress() {
        System.out.println("Enter the address: ");
        this.address = sc.nextLine();
    }

    public void editContact() {
        String choiceField;
        System.out.println("Select a field (organization name, address, number): ");
        choiceField = sc.nextLine();
        switch (choiceField) {
            case "name":
                this.setOraganizationName();
                break;
            case "address":
                this.setOrganizationAdress();
                break;
            case "number":
                this.setNumber();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong field name");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says exactly what the problem is: the Scanner class is not serializable. You never implemented a method of serializing it, so you will have errors.

Comment: Instead of including the Scanner in your class (which means you have a new Scanner object for each contact, and that doesn't make sense at all), try passing it as a parameter to every method that needs it, and then you only need 1 for the whole application (plus your contacts will be serializable).

Comment: Yes you are totally right, makes no sense have it in the Contact class. Can you make me an example? Thank You

Comment: I don't have time right now to make a correct example, but just create a Scanner in main(), get user input there as well (just checked and the only thing you use it for is in setters, which should be getting passed the data anyways by the calling function, and not requesting it from the user)

Comment: you can look up how setters work in Java (and other languages as well) for more info

Comment: For now i solved without getting any error when i write a record by using the keyword transient Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) which prevent the field to be serialized; But for some reason when i go check the file txt it was completely empty. Using the full path it wrote correctly :) it if i open the file it still says that "the file was open with a wrong encoding UTF-8" I you have time can you make me an example of how you would implement the scanner along the full program? Thank You for your time

Comment: What is unclear about "only take user input in App.java and then pass it to other functions"? do you know how to use function parameters?

Comment: Yes i know, but i was just wondering how you would do it. That's it. I'm a beginner and whenever possible i prefer to have a look to better styled code than what i'm capable of. Just for learning purpose. In any case thank You